# Two Different \mathcal Fonts in Same Document

Tags: fonts, mathcal

I would like to use the script C from `eucal` as well as the usual `\mathcal{B}` in the same document. The problem is, when I insert `\usepackage{eucal}` this changes the `\mathcal` script. How can I take advantage of both? I found the following [table](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/SMS/texdoc/euscript.pdf) (reprinted below) that seems to present the answer using `\mathscr` to preserve the old `\mathcal`, but I was not able to figure out how to properly do so.[image: Table]

I am currently using:

```
%latex
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
```

Here are close-up pictures of the C and B that I would like to use:

[image: C][image: B]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{C}\mathscr{C}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the sake of completeness, to get what the original post of @page, one needs to write `$\mathscr{C}\mathcal{B}$`